# Twain always returns TWRC_NOTDSEVENT

Tags: twain

I use twain 2.3 (TWAINDSM.DLL) in my application with HP Scanjet 200 TWAIN Protocol 1.9.

My TWAIIN calls are:

```
OpenDSM: DG_CONTROL, DAT_PARENT, MSG_OPENDSM

OpenDS: DG_CONTROL, DAT_IDENTITY, MSG_OPENDS

EnableDS: DG_CONTROL, DAT_USERINTERFACE, MSG_ENABLEDS

ProcessDeviceEvent: DG_CONTROL, DAT_EVENT, MSG_PROCESSEVENT
```

and as a result of the last call I allways get `TWRC_NOTDSEVENT` instead of `TWRC_DSEVENT`.

Could please someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you use `DG_CONTROL / DAT_EVENT / MSG_PROCESSEVENT`, all messages from the applications message loop must be sent to the data source for processing.  Receiving `TWRC_NOTDSEVENT` means the forwarded message isn't for the source so the application should process it as normal.

Keep forwarding all messages to the source until you receive `MSG_XFERREADY` which means there is data to transfer.  Once the transfer is finished and you have sent `MSG_DISABLEDS` that's when you can stop forwarding messages to the source.

Answer (score 0):

Twain is a standard, and when many company implement that standard, not all of them do the same way. Along the way to support Twain, we will learn and adjust the code to support all the different implementations.

I experienced this situation before, and this is my workaround:
Instead of placing (rc == TWRC_DSEVENT) at the beginning of code (will skip the following MSG_XFERREADY processing afterward) you can move the comparison to the end after MSG_XFERREADY processing, so that MSG_XFERREADY is always checked and processed.
(rc == TWRC_DSEVENT) is only to determine if we should forward the window message or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific situation. I ran into a similar issue because I called `OpenDSM` with a HWND/wId which is from another process. You should call `OpenDSM` with the HWND of
the active window/dialog which is owned by current process.